# Waiting for thesis corrections from supervisor, how should I write an email reminding him?

Tags: thesis, advisor, email, supervision

I sent part of my thesis to my supervisor a month ago. He replied that he would contact me as soon as he finished the correction.
I'm afraid he forgot that.

Would you have an example of a formal email to boost the demand?

Comment: What kind of thesis? PhD, Master's, Bachelor?

Comment: A gentle reminder is usually fine - keep it short but polite. Waiting on corrections is stressful, but reviewing theses can also be time-consuming and challenging, especially when other concerns arise.

Comment: Just ask. No special format necessary. Just be polite and ask if the review will be done soon. "Boosting" may not be possible, though.